# Set value on rows if at least one row has met the criteria

Tags: excel

I have the a datatable with orders information.

If at least one of the orders' Flag has a "Y", I need to set "1" to all the rows with the same order number, and 0 to the rest, such as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your picture starting in A1, put this in D2 and copy down:

```
=--COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"Y")>0
```